# Shiny reactive function behavior is not as expected

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I want to have my user upload two csv files. Only after this done do I want to send a data table to lm in `renderTable`, generate results and create a table from the output of a regression model. The basics of ui and server code are below. I use fileInput to read in the data. The server uses reactive construction to construct `dataInput` involving `if (is.null) return(NULL)` for each of the csv files. I thought this would essentially stop the `renderTable` code from doing anything until both csv files are uploaded. But in fact renderTable is still reacting. But I may be misunderstanding how to use reactive functions to pass a data table to another reactive function.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generate calibration parameters"),
  # Sidebar with two csv imports 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('master', 'Choose the master AQE CSV File',
                accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated values,text/plain', '.csv')),
      fileInput('slave', 'Choose the slave AQE CSV File',
                accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'))
    ),
    mainPanel(width = "100%",
              fluidRow(align = "center",
                       column(
                         width = 6, div(tableOutput("coeffTableO3"), style = "font-size:80%")
                       ))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataInput <- reactive({
    masterInfo <- input$master
    if (is.null(masterInfo))
      return(NULL)
    dt.master <- read_csv(masterInfo$datapath)
     dt.master <- as.data.table(dt.master)

    slaveInfo <- input$master
    if (is.null(slaveInfo))
      return(NULL)

    dt.slave <- as.data.table(read_csv(slaveInfo$datapath)

    timezone <- "America/Denver"

    #aggregate to minutes; note that cut returns a factor 'timestamp' becomes 'cut'
    varsToAgg.master <- c("no2", "o3")
    dt.master.min <- dt.master[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = list(cut(dt.master$timestamp, breaks = "min")), .SDcols = varsToAgg.master]
    varsToAgg.slave <- c("no2.slave", "o3.slave")
    dt.slave.min <- dt.slave[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = list(cut(dt.slave$timestamp.slave, breaks = "min")), .SDcols = varsToAgg.slave]

    # combine the two
    combinedResults <- merge(dt.master.min, dt.slave.min, by = 'cut')
    # convert cut back to posix and change name to time
    combinedResults[, time := as.POSIXct(cut,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = timezone)]
    combinedResults[,cut := NULL]
    return(combinedResults)

  })

  output$coeffTableO3 <- renderTable({
    # generate regression results
    combinedResults <- dataInput()
    print(str(combinedResults))
    lmResultsO3 <- lm(o3.slave ~ o3, combinedResults)
    coef(summary(lmResultsO3))["o3","Estimate"]
    coef(summary(lmResultsO3))["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `slaveInfo <- input$master` is that what you want? Shouldn't it be  `slaveInfo <- input$slave`? You probably forgot to add closing bracket to `dt.slave <- as.data.table(read_csv(slaveInfo$datapath)`. At the end of the code of `ui` you have many brackets `))))))` - there is one to much. `renderTable` is probably going to print the last line - `coef(summary(lmResultsO3))["(Intercept)","Estimate"]` (combine these two lines)

Comment: With the help of this comment I found and fixed a bunch of my coding errors. Now I know what behavior I should expect!

Comment: Why would you do `as.data.table(read_csv)` when `fread` is faster and imports as `data.table` by default?